# ReactJS ReactCSSTransitionGroup why does it work one component but not another?

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

Trying to figure out why this ReactCSSTransitionGroup animation works:

```
class SlideExample extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { visible: false };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({ visible: ! this.state.visible });
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.visible ? 'Slide up' : 'Slide down'}</button>
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
                transitionName="example"
                transitionEnterTimeout={300}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
                { 
                    this.state.visible 
                    ? <div className='panel'>
                        <ul className="project-list">
                            <li>one</li>
                            <li>two</li>
                            <li>three</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> 
                    : null 
                }
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
    }
}


const ProjectList = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="ProjectList">
            <SlideExample />
        </div> 
    );
}
```

But not like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            _isProjectNavOpen: true,
        }
    }
    _toggleProjectNav() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            _isProjectNavOpen: !prevState._isProjectNavOpen,
        }));
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="App">
                <Router>
                    <div className="main-content">
                        <Route path="/projects" component={(props, state, params) => 
                            <ProjectList 
                                _toggleProjectNav={this._toggleProjectNav} 
                                _isProjectNavOpen={this.state._isProjectNavOpen} 
                            {...props} />} />
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const ProjectList = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="ProjectList">
            <div className="center title" onClick={props._toggleProjectNav} id="Menu">Menu</div>

            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
                transitionName="example"
                transitionEnterTimeout={300}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
                { 
                    props._isProjectNavOpen 
                    ? <div className='panel'>
                        <ul className="project-list">
                            <li>xx one</li>
                            <li>xx two</li>
                            <li>xx three</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> 
                    : null 
                }
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>

        </div>
    );
}
```

The CSS:

```
.panel {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.example-enter {
    height: 0px;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
    height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease;
}
```

_toggleProjectNav is a prop passed down from a parent component that toggles the _isProjectNavOpen state true/false; it works in that the panel does hide/show, but without the animation... does it have to do with the state being passed from the parent? Trying to understand how ReactCSSTransitionGroup works.

Thanks!

Comment: css is responsible for the animation. by any chance maybe you have not added the css?

Comment: Added the CSS to the original post, works in the first example and not for the second.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. In this case this is not a ReactCSSTransitionGroup issue. The issue is most probably related to the CSS. Pay attention, some browsers require initial height value before the transition. So you need something like this:

```
.example-leave {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Hm.. no added that and still not working for me; from what I can tell in the first case .example-enter and .example-leave attach to transition hide/show, but in the second case it does not. Interesting that the same code works on your end..

Comment: It also might depends on the parent elements layout. Could you show how are you rendering the *ProjectList* component

Comment: Yes! Appended to original comment (note the ProjectList is being rendered inside a Route component... might this have to do why?

Comment: Still work for me except two things.
First, why do you keep __toggleProjectNav_ within a _contructor_? The sintax doesn't look valid. It might be valid if you'll move it outside the _constructor_

Comment: Next, the _panel_ takes the animation, but _ul_ doesn't, as it's placed inside the _panel_.
_ReactCSSTransitionGroup_ attaches animation classes only to the direct child elements, it doesn't touch nested elements. And, you should consider, that the element won't be unmounted until the animation will be finished. In your case, the _panel_ is taking the animation, than waiting for it's end, than unmounting.
Check if the animation works for *panel*. If it's OK, you may add the `overflow: hidden;` to the `.panel` class for closing the _ul_ with the _panel_

Comment: Thanks, the _toggleProjectNav placement within the constructor was just a typo in my Stackoverflow comment, and I corrected. However, I still have a problem getting the animation to attach in the second example -- ignoring the child elements; on the panel itself -- to test I added background colors, for on-enter and on-leave. While I see the panel background change in the first example, it never does in the second... going to continue to try and figure this out. Thx for your advise tho